# The requested URL /magento/ was not found on this server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, magento

I try to install magaento2 with php7 apache2 from web.

it succeded. Installation succeeded.

```
Magento Admin Info:

Username:
admin
Email:
admin@test.com
Password:
******
Your Store Address:
http://localhost/magento/
Magento Admin Address:
http://localhost/magento/admin/
```

but when i click those linkss

i got error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /magento/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

in other topics, people say

go to

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d
```

and some lines. But at that directory, i hve a lot of ini, it is not a texxtfile

```
“/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d” is a directory.
```

when i try to open wit gedit

what can i do now?

but for

```
gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

it shows

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

when i change some parts, it affects the localhost root. for example when i dsable, localhost becomes forbidden.

this is error log

```
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:07.838247 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:07.838287 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:10.217465 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:10.264056 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:10.264067 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

in

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

i also created apache.conf like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/magento.conf
```

and theen did this

```
sudo a2ensite magento.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

i looked from here but

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04

but nothing changed

this is error log

```
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:07.838247 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:07.838287 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:10.217465 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:10.264056 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:08:10.264067 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:00.449232 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:00.507141 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:00.507153 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:43.105955 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:43.153499 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:43.153511 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:48.271177 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27202] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:49.447808 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27820] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:16:49.447838 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27820] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:17:51.567331 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27820] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 10:17:51.614927 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27820] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:17:51.614939 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27820] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:17:52.825263 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27820] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 10:17:53.964814 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27945] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:17:53.964843 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27945] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:41:21.587129 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27945] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 10:41:22.768479 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29209] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:41:22.768509 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29209] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 10:42:13.155839 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29209] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 10:42:14.279786 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29294] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 10:42:14.279817 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29294] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:08:48.917446 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29294] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:08:49.998267 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30868] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:08:49.998299 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30868] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:12:36.227958 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30868] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 11:12:36.276950 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30868] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:12:36.276962 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30868] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:12:43.920686 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30868] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:12:44.975202 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31184] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:12:44.975231 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31184] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:15:09.691761 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31184] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:15:10.852670 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31344] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:15:10.852705 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31344] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:15:13.627029 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31344] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 11:15:13.675088 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31344] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:15:13.675101 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31344] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:17:09.348813 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31344] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 11:17:09.395006 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31344] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:17:09.395019 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31344] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:17:13.322077 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31344] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:17:14.497462 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31549] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:17:14.497501 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31549] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:21:17.796019 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31549] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:21:18.939220 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31739] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:21:18.939252 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31739] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:21:21.925933 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31739] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Sep 08 11:21:21.971902 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31739] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:21:21.971914 2016] [core:notice] [pid 31739] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:27:29.795435 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31739] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:27:30.880443 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32048] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:27:30.880477 2016] [core:notice] [pid 32048] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:41:14.883168 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32048] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:41:16.021082 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 606] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:41:16.021125 2016] [core:notice] [pid 606] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:47:06.305602 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 606] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:47:07.457794 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 864] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:47:07.457825 2016] [core:notice] [pid 864] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:50:48.006471 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 864] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:50:49.149710 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1126] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:50:49.149743 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1126] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 08 11:51:20.235219 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1126] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 08 11:51:21.377260 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1210] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 11:51:21.377295 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1210] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

for

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

i did

https://askubuntu.com/a/448403/590851

here

those are logs which @gloom700 suggested

```
Generate custom log for your site. Below DocumentRoot add 2 lines . "CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-access.log combined" "ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-error.log" Restart the service and check these log files
```

i put those to my apache conf.

this is error log only after apache restart

```
[Thu Sep 08 12:38:08.630069 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4059] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 12:38:08.630108 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4059] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'


now i try to navigate to
```

localhost/magento

no errorlog but for acccess

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:38:49 +0300] "GET /magento HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
```

now i try to navigate to

localhost/magento2
url changes to

http://localhost/magento/?SID=cq4mo1k2p1pik3me0ufk0p7ae4

access log (inclding previosu)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:38:49 +0300] "GET /magento HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento/?SID=cq4mo1k2p1pik3me0ufk0p7ae4 HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
```

error log

```
[Thu Sep 08 12:38:08.630069 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4059] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 12:38:08.630108 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4059] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

now magento/admin
no error but accesss

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:38:49 +0300] "GET /magento HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento/?SID=cq4mo1k2p1pik3me0ufk0p7ae4 HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:40:44 +0300] "GET /magento/admin HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
```

now magento/setup

access

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:38:49 +0300] "GET /magento HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento/?SID=cq4mo1k2p1pik3me0ufk0p7ae4 HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:40:44 +0300] "GET /magento/admin HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:41:20 +0300] "GET /magento/setup/ HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
```

error

```
[Thu Sep 08 12:38:08.630069 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4059] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 08 12:38:08.630108 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4059] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

i think error still was nt changed

now magento 2/admin

access

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:38:49 +0300] "GET /magento HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento/?SID=cq4mo1k2p1pik3me0ufk0p7ae4 HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:40:44 +0300] "GET /magento/admin HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:41:20 +0300] "GET /magento/setup/ HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:42:10 +0300] "GET /magento2/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 647 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:42:14 +0300] "GET /magento/admin/admin/index/index/key/5693df064035428c19e5fa184b4afa34e077e014143dd178179a37cff78cb0e1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 590 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:38:49 +0300] "GET /magento HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:39:25 +0300] "GET /magento/?SID=cq4mo1k2p1pik3me0ufk0p7ae4 HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:40:44 +0300] "GET /magento/admin HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:41:20 +0300] "GET /magento/setup/ HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:42:10 +0300] "GET /magento2/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 647 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:12:42:14 +0300] "GET /magento/admin/admin/index/index/key/5693df064035428c19e5fa184b4afa34e077e014143dd178179a37cff78cb0e1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 590 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"
```

error
same stilli think.

Comment: What URL are you using to access magenta ? Are you trying to access it from an external machine or from the one containing the installation ?

Comment: the one contatining the installation . it is localhost. i use the urls it gave after success. localhost/magento and localhost/magento/admin (i created those links in installation) . with php5.6, i could see store with same urls and settings but now i have php 7 but cant see anything.

Comment: Verify that there are access.log entries for your connections.

Comment: i couldnot because i havve deleted inside to see what will be new

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache after deleting your log.

Comment: YEs i did but still log is emtpy.sudo service apache2 restart
 idid this and go to localhost/magento but log is empty. THen i  did reload and others but still empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to disable php5. Run the command a2dismod php5

Comment: No, there is nnot any left. i ran and it says php5 dosnot exist

Comment: enable php 7 and check .  a2enmod php7.0

Comment: i think it is enabled too sudo a2enmod php7.0 
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.0:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:
Module php7.0 already enabled

Comment: Generate custom log for your site. Below DocumentRoot add 2 lines .  "CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-access.log  combined"                          "ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/mysite-error.log"                                                    Restart the service and check these log files

Comment: in apache.conf? **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf **
 here?

Comment: apache.conf. between <VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>

Comment: i dont have virtual there but i put lines bottom. you can see my apacheconf in question.

Comment: Let's discuss in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45086/discussion-between-gloom700-and-fff).

Comment: please look at my question, i posted

Comment: it works after i change my folder magento2 to magento. but why? and still cant add item to cart

Answer (score 1):

Given that your access.log and error.log are not logging anything I am going to suggest that you are not connecting to the system you think you are.

Comment: i can see error log. i added to question edit.

Comment: That is not the error message you would see for the error you have.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like a rewrite issue.

look in /var/www/html

for a file with htaccess in the title. it needs to be named exactly .htaccess magento being a largely used cms should include a default one.

if its not named exactly .htaccess rename it.

then ensure that your apache install is setup to run rewrites. you can do this with the following:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then try to go to localhost/magento/

This may resolve your problem.

if it does not, ensure that your install dir is in fact /var/www/html/magento and report back your findings.

Comment: i couldnot find it, maybe it is hiden? i did all here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html and rewrite already enabled. should i creatae htacces..? it says put bottom but i did not want to put after this **</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet **  so i put directory thing given there before **virtual host tag**

Comment: Hmm. You installed Apache via apt correct? Can you post the output of ls - lah /var/www/html

Comment: BTW, the  # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet ** is just a VIM setting override string. if you do not use VIM to edit with, you can remove it with no ill effects.

Comment: i did not install with apt correct i think. this is output **drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data 4,0K Eyl  9 10:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4,0K Eyl  5 00:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4,0K Eyl  8 17:32 cd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  12K Eyl  5 00:52 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   21 Eyl  5 10:05 info.php
drwxrwx--- 12 www-data www-data 4,0K Eyl  9 10:52 magento2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   14 Eyl  5 12:46 ss.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4,0K Eyl  8 18:53 tm**

Comment: Owner/group looks right.

But I notice that the dir name is magento2 and not magento. according to your site-avail config, /var/www/html is your root directory. So navigating via browser to http://localhost will take you here. so to view magento, you need to go to http://locahost/magento2 as this is the directory name of the install. Try that.